# Hash Table keys outputs a single string instead of an array

Tags: powershell

Why is the hash table output a single string not a array?

```
$ServicesList = @{
    "Exhange Online"               = "Connect-ExchangeOnline"
    "Security & Compliance Center" = "Connect-IPPSSession"
    "Azure Active Directory"       = "Connect-AzureAD"
    "Microsoft Online"             = "Connect-MsolService"
    "SharePoint Online"            = "Connect-SPOService -Url $url"
    "Microsoft Teams"              = "Connect-MicrosoftTeams"
    "Microsoft Graph"              = "Connect-Graph"
    "Azure Account"                = "Connect-AzAccount"
}

$ServicesListKeys = $ServicesList.Keys

function Menu {
    $menu = @{}
    for ($i = 1; $i -le $ServicesListKeys.count; $i++) {
        Write-Host "$i. $($ServicesListKeys[$i-1])" 
        $menu.Add($i, ($ServicesListKeys[$i - 1]))
    }
    [int]$ans = Read-Host 'Enter selection'
    $selection = $menu.Item($ans) ; $ServicesList[$selection]
}

Menu
```

Output:

1. Azure Active Directory Microsoft Graph Microsoft Online Azure Account Security & Compliance Center Exhange Online Microsoft Teams SharePoint Online
2. 
3. 
4. 
5. 
6. 
7. 
8. 

when it workers with a normal array

```
$array = "Red", "green", "Blue"
```

Output:

1. Red
2. green
3. Blue

Comment: ```$ServicesListKeys``` is not indexable, so PowerShell returns the object itself for ```$ServicesListKeys[0]```, and `````$null``` for all other indices. Compare to ```(1`)[0]``` (returns ```1```) vs ```(1)[1]``` (returns ```$null```). You can coerce it into an array with ```$ServicesListKeys =@( $ServicesList.Keys )``` and then your remaining code will work fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Hashtable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable?view=net-6.0) only supports [`Item[Object]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.item?view=net-6.0#system-collections-hashtable-item(system-object)):

> Gets or sets the value associated with the specified key.

Whereas [`OrderedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary?view=net-6.0) supports both, [`Item[Object]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.item?view=net-6.0#system-collections-specialized-ordereddictionary-item(system-object)) and [`Item[Int32]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.item?view=net-6.0#system-collections-specialized-ordereddictionary-item(system-int32)), the latter being:

> Gets or sets the value at the specified index.

In this case you could simply change your hashtable for an ordered dictionary, not only because it supports getting values by **index** but also because the key / value pairs will always retain the same order. By using a hashtable, the items on your Menu not always have the same order.

Here is a simplified working version of your code:

```bash
$ServicesList = [ordered]@{
    "Exhange Online"               = "Connect-ExchangeOnline"
    "Security & Compliance Center" = "Connect-IPPSSession"
    "Azure Active Directory"       = "Connect-AzureAD"
    "Microsoft Online"             = "Connect-MsolService"
    "SharePoint Online"            = "Connect-SPOService -Url $url"
    "Microsoft Teams"              = "Connect-MicrosoftTeams"
    "Microsoft Graph"              = "Connect-Graph"
    "Azure Account"                = "Connect-AzAccount"
}

function Menu {
    param($Dictionary)

    $i = 1; $ServicesList.PSBase.Keys | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "$(($i++)). $_"
    }

    [int] $ans = Read-Host 'Enter selection'

    if($value = $Dictionary[$ans - 1]) {
        return $value
    }
    Write-Warning "Invalid selection!"
}

Menu -Dictionary $ServicesList
```

Comment: Your code returns: 1.Exhange Online Security & Compliance Center Azure Active Directory Microsoft Online SharePoint Online Microsoft Teams Microsoft Graph Azure Account
2.
3.
4.
5.
6.
7.
8.
Enter selection:

Comment: @ScratchIV that was my bad, it behaves different in pwsh 7 and pwsh 5. in pwsh 7 something like `$ServicesList.Keys[0]` would work fine. Please try again with the updated version